# mysqldump won't accept combination of --socket, --all-databses, --user, --password

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump

Linux, 2 mariadbs each with their own .sock.

Dump as root works fine:

```
[root@host]$ mysqldump --socket=/tmp/mysqlsecond.sock --all-databases > $sqlfile
```

Dump as the non-root backup user requires user and password args so I added those:

```
[backup@host]$ mysqldump --socket=/tmp/mysqlsecond.sock --user $user --password $password --all-databases> $sqlfile
```

But the result is:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --system=[SYSTEMOPTIONS]]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

I made the backup user on the master DB as well (to try without --socket):

```
mysqldump --user $user --password $password --all-databases > $sqlfile
```

But same usage print-out. I tried various arg order, what's the conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--user=$user --password=$password` as shown in the help for mysqldump. You may also include the user name and password in the INI file in the `[mysqldump]` section to avoid using it on the command line.